# In Chrome, <embed> resource isn't loaded when $(document).ready() is triggered. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In Firefox and IE, the SVG `<embed>` (SVG) document is retrieved when `$(document ).ready()` is called.

In Chrome, the `getSVGDocument` returns null instead when `$(document ).ready()` is called. (Although it seems to find it approx 7ms after, as shown by the `setTimeout`.)

Why does Chrome not find the loaded `<embed>` SVGdocument at moment of `$(document ).ready()`, but Firefox and IE do?

(I don't want to have to use a `setTimeout(7ms)` just to wait for Chrome to catch up! Because that's... lame.)

The code simple code below shows scenario: **RETURNS SVGDocument** in Firefox + IE **RETURNS NULL** in Chrome (unless the call to `getSVG()` is delayed by 7ms!).

N.B: This code needs to be run on `localhost` server with Chrome; that is a separate Chrome issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>

    getSVG = function () {

        var el = document.getElementById("embedId");

        SVGDoc = el.getSVGDocument();

        console.log(SVGDoc);                           // returns null in Chrome

    }



    $(document).ready(function () {

        getSVG();                        

        //setTimeout("getSVG()", 7);      // this works, showing that Chrome is NOT "ready"

    });


</script>

</head>

<body>

<embed id="embedId" src="man.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="50" height="50"/> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Depends maybe how chrome is handling DOM events. Whats give window.onload = function(){...} ???

Comment: The "ready" event happens when the DOM is fully built but potentially *before* other resources (images, embeds, etc) are loaded.

Comment: The element IS "ready" since you can select it, however it's contents are not loaded yet.

Comment: @roasted Not sure what you mean "whats give window.onload = function(){...}???"

Comment: @Pointy  This all makes sense, thanks for the insight. However, same shouldn't be true for the window.onload event. (Chrome just effs up there i think)

Comment: @matt The "load" event and the "ready" event have different semantics. The "load" event fires when *everything* has been loaded. Chrome is working within the tolerance of the spec here.

Comment: @Pointy I agree with you about the semantics completely. That's what I'm saying (as far as my Chrome goes anyway) the "load" event IS firing BEFORE my embed content has loaded!!! (window.load that is, NOT jQuery's $(window).load)

Comment: @matt the "load" event via jQuery is the native browser event.  The "ready" event is also native in Chrome I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log($('#embedId')[0].getSVGDocument());
});
```

Another possible solution:

```
$(function(){
    var a = $('#embedId')[0];

    a.addEventListener("load",function(){

        //do stuff with 'a'

    },false);
});
```

Comment: Cheers Johan, $(window).load() is just what i needed! The second solution though: how does the jQuery function work. I've never used a jQuery wrapped function... how is it executed?

Comment: The "jQuery wrapped" solution is just another way of setting up a "ready" handler, so it will **not** work.

Comment: @Pointy Combined with the load event listener it should.

Comment: @Johan ah yes you're right, I didn't even see that!  Completely OK then.

Comment: so waa do you do with it... $(window).load($(yourJQueryFunction))... or... $(document).ready($(yourJQueryFunction))...

Comment: @matt document ready is fired when the DOM has loaded.

window onload waits for the assets in the page to be completely loaded (images for example)

Comment: @Johan , ah yes I've just seen it too. Great, thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

You should use $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() to wait for loaded embbeds, iframes and images

Comment: That did the trick nicely! I never new that existed. Cheers Diego, Simple, right under my nose. Still a little annoyed that the native onload doesn't work right in Chrome, but this has made my day! :)