# How to add a loading mask to simple request from <html> tag

Tags: html

I am requesting for a PDF from server by doing this:

```
html: '<embed type="application/pdf" width="1500px" height="800px" src="' + src + '"/>'
```

Now I know it is very easy to add a loading mask to AJAX Request but how about adding it to the above mentioned request. Lets say if I do this:

```
Ext.loadMask();
html: '<embed type="application/pdf" width="1500px" height="800px" src="' + src + '"/>'
Ext.hideMask();
```

The hideMask() gets called even before the response is returned from the server.

I tried onload as well like this:

```
html: '<embed type="application/pdf" width="1500px" height="800px" src="' + src + '" onload=' + console.log("this PDf has been loaded") + '/>'
```

But even this gets called even before I see the PDF

Answer (score 0):

You stated right that in your provided code you have async code executed, because of your request.

What you can do is try to implement a risky event listener that might work, but it is a subject to debate across different browsers.

Something like :

```
var targetEl = document.getElementByID("target");
targetEl.innerHTML = '<embed id="embeded" type="application/pdf" width="1500px" height="800px" src="' + src + '"/>';
embeded = document.getElementByID("embeded");
embeded.addEventListener("load", function() { Ext.hideMask(); });
```

But you will definitely not be sure if this will work across all browsers. Better alternative is to use `$("#embed").on('load', function() { ... });` - jQuery library.

References:

- [In Chrome, <embed> resource isn't loaded when $(document).ready() is triggered. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013795/in-chrome-embed-resource-isnt-loaded-when-document-ready-is-triggered)
- [Javascript - load events for embed elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740860/javascript-load-events-for-embed-elements)

Comment: I tried onload as well like this:
html: '<embed type="application/pdf" width="1500px" height="800px" src="' + src + '" onload=' + console.log("this PDf has been loaded") + '/>'
But even this gets called even before I see the PDF

Comment: usually it's very difficult to control what has happened in the embeded tag ( and iframe for that matter ). That's why service providers give their own APIs for giving back some information to the parent DOM element. You can read a bit more for embedding PDFs to your website on [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html).